# How to animate todo moving from one list to another with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, animation, vuejs2, css-grid

> I am trying to do [this svelte example](https://svelte.dev/examples#animate) todo moving animation with Vue.js.

Below you can find what I have done so far. Just click on the todo to see.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
     { id: 1, name: 'John', done: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jane', done: false },
      { id: 3, name: 'Jade', done: true },
      { id: 4, name: 'George', done: true },
    ]
  },
  
  computed: {
   done () {
     return this.items.filter(i => i.done)
    },
    
    undone () {
     return this.items.filter(i => !i.done)
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.todos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.todo {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.todo.undone {
  grid-column: 2 /span 1;
}

.todo.done {
  grid-column: 1 /span 1;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.flip-list-move {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  
}

.header, .todo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">


  <div class="header-wrapper">
   <div class="header">
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>Gender</span>
  </div>
  
    <div class="header">
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>Gender</span>
  </div>
  </div>

  <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="div" class="todos">

    <div class="todo done" v-for="item of done" :key="item.id" @click="toggle(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <span>26</span>
      <span>Male</span>
    </div>

    <div class="todo undone" v-for="item of undone" :key="item.id" @click="toggle(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <span>20</span>
      <span>Male</span>
    </div> 

   
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

In order to animate the todo move from one list to another, I used CSS grid but I can't find a way to distinguish todos (left and right) without having a grid cell which is empty.

I would appreciate if there is a better way to achieve the example in svelte docs or a way to omit the empty cells.

Even though it seemed easy in the beginning, it's a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding `grid-row-start` to the first undone element doesn't works if there are more than 6 items in array.

As a solution, I used the `index` of `v-for` loop to add to every **undone** todo the corresponding `grid-row-start`.

**`index` starts at 0 so we have to make `index + 1`**

```
  <div
    class="todo undone"
    v-for="(item, index) of undone"
    :key="item.id"
    :style="{'grid-row': index + 1}" // => HERE we guarantee no gaps are present in undone list`
    @click="toggle(item)"
  >
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <span>20</span>
    <span>Male</span>
  </div>
```

You can find the working example [on this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-move-todos-from-one-list-to-another-xgtrv)

Answer (score 5):

You can target the first element by tracking the `index` in the `v-for` loop. Index `0` is always going to be the first element. And give it the following style:

`grid-row-start: 1;`

**EDIT DEMO:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
     { id: 1, name: 'John', done: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jane', done: false },
      { id: 3, name: 'Jade', done: true },
      { id: 4, name: 'George', done: true },
    ]
  },
  
  computed: {
   done () {
     return this.items.filter(i => i.done)
    },
    
    undone () {
     return this.items.filter(i => !i.done)
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.todos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.todo {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.todo.undone {
  grid-column: 2 /span 1;
}

.todo.done {
  grid-column: 1 /span 1;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.first-right {
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

.flip-list-move {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  
}

.header, .todo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">


  <div class="header-wrapper">
   <div class="header">
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>Gender</span>
  </div>
  
    <div class="header">
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>Gender</span>
  </div>
  </div>

  <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="div" class="todos">

    <div class="todo done" v-for="item of done" :key="item.id" @click="toggle(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <span>26</span>
      <span>Male</span>
    </div>

    <div :class="['todo', 'undone', { 'first-right': index === 0 }]" v-for="(item, index) of undone" :key="item.id" @click="toggle(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <span>20</span>
      <span>Male</span>
    </div> 

   
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. You can't target the first undone because you can't see it. The first undone you target is the empty row. Even if you catch the second one again it will not work

Comment: Ok I got it to work, check the code snippet I added to my post...

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment targeting the first undone it will not work. In your example, if you add 6 items in array, you will see that it doesn't works. However I added an answer to my question which works pretty well.